# How do I plot multiple time series grouped by different colours?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, series

I am trying to have a single graph displaying a 10 series. These are divided in group such as this simple example :

```
            Group A | Group B
   time(h)  S1 S2 S3   S4 S5 S6
     0      1  3   1   3  4  5
     24     2  1   3   4  2  1
     48     3  2   2   1  2  2
```

How can I add these 6 series in a single graph and categorise their group A/B by colour ?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.lineplot(data=df.stack(level=[0,1]).reset_index(name='value'),
             x='time', y='value', hue='level_1', style='level_2' 
            )
```

And you would get:

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks I am importing from excel as:  Data = r"C:\path.xlsm"
df= pd.read_excel(Data)

Comment: Try with `df = pd.read_excel(Data,index_col=0, header=[0,1])`

Comment: thanks again! If you were to code for the particular example of dataframe I posted how would the code look like, adding the colours for group A and B. Y axis are the values and the X value is the time in the first column. Sorry to bother again!