# How can I plot several series in groups in Julia?

Tags: plot, julia

I am trying to plot a large number of line series in Julia, and I want to use two colors to differentiate between two groups.

With the code below, which uses a small dataset, I get the following:

```
using Plots
toy = rand(10, 5)
color = rand(0:1, 5)
full = vcat(toy, color')

plot(full, label = color)
```

[image]

What I am trying to do is to have only two colours, corresponding to the value in "color" {0, 1}. How can I do that?

PS: I have seen a similar question for matplotlib: [How do I plot multiple time series grouped by different colours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65832228/how-do-i-plot-multiple-time-series-grouped-by-different-colours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `color` keyword argument?

```
plot(full; color=color', title="colors = $color")
```

gives me

[image]

PS1: If you want the default 1st and 2nd colors, your `color` values must start at 1, such that

```
plot(full; color=color' .+ 1, title="colors = $color")
```

gives me

[image]

PS2: If you want more control on the colors, you can do that as well, e.g.,

```
plot(full; color=([RGB(1,0,0), RGB(0,1,0)][color .+ 1])', title="colors = $color")
```

gives me

[image]

Comment: How do you make sure the legend reads something like "Color 1 = label1; Color 2 = label2" instead of a list of all series and their corresponding color?